# how to set User administrator role to azure active directory application through graph API

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I want to delete a user from azure AD B2C using graph API. I register a new application for this purpose to get permission for graph API.
[Create app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-applications?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

1. Then i create a service principle for  application using below link
   [Create Service principle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-serviceprincipals?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
2. next step is user role assignment to application.I want to set user administer role to application
   [image]

> ```
> POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/{resource-id}/appRoleAssignedTo
> { "principalId": "{principal-id}", 
>   "resourceId": "{resource-id}", 
>   "appRoleId": "{app-role-id}" 
> }
> ```

i got the service principle id from service principle object
@odata.context                         :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#servicePrincipals/$entity
id                                     : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
deletedDateTime                        : 
accountEnabled                         : True
alternativeNames                       : {}
appDisplayName                         : xxx
appDescription                         : 
appId                                  : xxxxxxxxxx
applicationTemplateId                  : 
appOwnerOrganizationId                 : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
appRoleAssignmentRequired              : False
createdDateTime                        : 
description                            : 
displayName                            : xxxx
homepage                               : 
loginUrl                               : 
logoutUrl                              : 
notes                                  : 
notificationEmailAddresses             : {}
preferredSingleSignOnMode              : 
preferredTokenSigningKeyThumbprint     : 
replyUrls                              : {}
resourceSpecificApplicationPermissions : {}
samlSingleSignOnSettings               : 
servicePrincipalNames                  : {cxxxxx}
servicePrincipalType                   : Application
signInAudience                         : AzureADMyOrg
tags                                   : {}
tokenEncryptionKeyId                   : 
verifiedPublisher                      : @{displayName=; verifiedPublisherId=; addedDateTime=}
addIns                                 : {}
appRoles                               : {}
info                                   : @{logoUrl=; marketingUrl=; privacyStatementUrl=; supportUrl=; termsOfServiceUrl=}
keyCredentials                         : {}
oauth2PermissionScopes                 : {}
passwordCredentials                    : {}
```

i assumed  principalId is id    of the object and resource id is same.
Then how do  i get the appRoleId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User Administrator is [a directory role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#user-administrator), not an app role.
You need to use this endpoint in MS Graph: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryrole-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http.

It requires that you do an HTTP POST request to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryRoles/{id}/members/$ref`.
Request body example from docs:

```json
{
  "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{user-id}"
}
```

If you are looking to assign this directory role to the service principal, I'm pretty sure you can set the service principal object id in the body instead of a user id.

You may need to find out the User Administrator role's id first from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryrole-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http.

Answer (score 1):

You want to grant the role `User.ReadWrite.All` to allow deleting users from Azure AD. As per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#application-permissions-62) this will require admin consent.

Using the endpoint https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications with this payload will create an app registration, with the proper role:

```
{
  "displayName": "My App",
  "requiredResourceAccess": [
    {
      "resourceAppId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
      "resourceAccess": [
        {
          "id": "741f803b-c850-494e-b5df-cde7c675a1ca",
          "type": "Role"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The endpoint is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/application-post-applications)

Comment: when called the above url     "appRoles": [] and  "requiredResourceAccess": [], is getting empty

Comment: Edited my response, to properly address your question.

Comment: Thanks for help. This is what i am looking. In the document it is not mentioned anything about the role right? Where i have to set "User.ReadWrite.All" permission in payload object. What does  this  "id": "741f803b-c850-494e-b5df-cde7c675a1ca" refer?